# Mysql doesn't return existing row from Aqua data studio or from Django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have a peculiar problem:

I have a table that in some columns it contains varchars and texts in Greek, sometimes mixed with some Engish.

When I make a select query like following:

```
select * from table where col_name = 'Greek String'
```

or

```
select * from table where col_name like '%Greek String%'
```

(Of course "Greek String" is with Greek letters)

If these queries are called from mysql console, they return the correct rows
If they are called from inside Aqua Data Studio or from Django (using the Django querying method, with data models), then they don't return anything!

The same queries return everything correctly from everywhere, if col_name = 'Latin String' or col_name like '%Latin String%'

The default character set of the database is latin1

The default character set of the table is greek and

The default character set of the columns which have the problem is also greek

Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The default character set of Django is utf8. The best way is to convert your database charset also to utf8. Otherwise you could set another character set in your settings.py, specifying key 'OPTIONS' under 'DATABASES' and adding something like:

`'OPTIONS': {
    'charset': 'latin1',
    'use_unicode': True, # this line could eventually also be needed
}`

I would however suggest to use utf8 consistently throughout the whole project. You can use Greek letters with utf8.

Comment: The official documentation says: 
You can create your database using the command-line tools and this SQL:

`CREATE DATABASE <dbname> CHARACTER SET utf8;`

This ensures all tables and columns will use UTF-8 by default.

For more details visit: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#creating-your-database

Comment: Than you, it's a useful thing to know!
The problem is that I use a legacy database which also contains lots of data, so the CHARACTER SET was already set when it was created.
Is there a safe way to change the CHARACTER SET of the existing database without dumping it, dropping it and recreating it ?